# How can I build a PureScript (*.purs) compiler for MeteorJS?

Tags: meteor, bower, purescript, pulp

I want some basic dependencies (Prelude, Console) to test my compiler package.
How can I use Bower inside my Meteor package to install those basic dependencies?

The "bower.json" example from a "PureScript Book" chapter:

```
{
  "name": "purescript-book-chapter2",
  "description": "Chapter 2 - Getting Started",
  "keywords": [
    "purescript"
  ],
  "ignore": [
    ...
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "purescript-console": "^0.1.0"
  }
}
```

I use these commands for building JS files from PS source: `bower install`, `bower update` (to install dependent libraries) and `pulp build` (for compiling *.purs to *.js).

Comment: Using bower directly with meteor is probably not the best choice, but to me It looks like your question has nothing to do with the bower itself. You're probably asking "how can I build a *.purs compiler for meteor?". If that's the case I think that changing the title would bring more attention to this question.

Comment: BTW, I can see that the original PureScript compilator is written in Haskell. In that case you may have some hard time trying to integrate it with Meteor. Do you know about any nodejs compatible solutions out there?

Comment: I use Pulp (a kind of Gulp) for compiling PureScript, it's very easy to use with Node. I did not install Haskell, just PureScript binaries.

Comment: PureScript tracking dependencies with Bower. Thank you for your comments. I try to change question...